# GCM iOS production environment

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem with running GCM on iOS with production environment. We use topic messaging and app successfully register to some topic e.g. /topic/global, but it receives notifications only for dev builds. I tested uploaded production pk12 certificate with apple apn directly and it works as it should. Production app is signed with enterprise certificate (don't know if it makes any difference).

Can somebody point what I'm doing wrong or what I should check again?

Comment: This seems like a configuration bug somewhere.  Are you setting `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` to NO for your Production app?

Comment: Yes I'm. I checked this numerous times :(

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the correct prod (and not sandbox) certificate when you registered with GCM? Also make sure you're properly signing your app for the prod version (I guess you can verify that the APNS token is different for your sandbox and prod app).

Comment: I checked it. I tested correct prod certificate agains APNS and it worked. Then I uploaded it to GCM.

Comment: Do you get any error when you do the GCM push or does it say success and just not deliver the message?

Comment: It says success and return me message id, but no notification is delivered to device.

Comment: Umm in the question you posted you said that you uploaded the "Prod certificate" to GCM but you're signing your app for the "enterprise version". If this is correct you might be required to upload the "enterprise" APNS certificate since it's different from the prod one.

Comment: I ment enteprise. That certificate is OK, because apns with it that works.

Comment: Ok this seems weird. Can you please file a bug(mail) here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-gcm. Also some details like your senderID and bundleID would be useful to debug what is wrong.

Also the message payload you're trying to send would be useful to have.

Comment: If you have an update it might be worth mentioning in an answer or the comments. I thought it would be something like this, but ended up with a NotRegistered error message when sending to a device that had a previous version of the app installed where the GCM was not correctly configured.

Answer (score 3):

Set `"priority": "high"`

```
{
      "to": "gcm_device_token",
      "priority": "high",
      "content_available": false,
      "notification": {
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": "1",
        "title": "Push Title",
        "body": "Push Body"
      }
    }
```

Here's the code to use for production environment :

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@NO};
```

Here's the code to use for development environment :

```
_registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
```